# Java. Как архивировать только определенные файлы из папки в один архив

Tags: java, zip

Всем привет. Может вопрос банальный, но в Java я новичок и никак не могу додуматься.

Проблема такая:

Есть папка, в ней много разных файлов. Я отбираю только нужные мне (по дате изменения). Использую java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream. А когда передаю файл в метод архивации, он делает мне отдельный архив для каждого файла. Есть какие-то способы, которые позволят сделать единый архив, без копирования/перемещения нужных файлов в отдельную папку?

Код, в котором из массива файлов выбираю нужные и передаю на архивацию:

```
for (File s : files) {

            BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(s.toPath(), BasicFileAttributes.class);
            if (dateChecker(attr.lastModifiedTime())) {                            
                ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(s.getPath() + ".zip"));
                doZip(s, out);
                out.close();
            }
        }
```

Метод архивации:

```
 void doZip(File dir, ZipOutputStream out){
    try {
        out.setLevel(9);
        out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(dir.getName()));
        write(new FileInputStream(dir), out);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static void write(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buffer)) >= 0)
        out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    in.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В действительности вы делаете несколько архивов своими руками.

```
for (File s : files) {    
    BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(s.toPath(), BasicFileAttributes.class);
    if (dateChecker(attr.lastModifiedTime())) {                            
        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(s.getPath() + ".zip"));
        doZip(s, out);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Здесь вы создаете для каждого следующего файла новый стрим (в цикле), а то есть и файл с новым названием, соответствующим `<имя файла>.zip`. И после архивации закрываете его, то есть создаете в файловой системе файл архива для конкретного файла.

Вам нужно создать один `ZipOutputStream` на всю обработку и при переборе файлов сохранять их в него. Это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
List<File> filesToArchive = new LinkedList<>();
for (File file : files) {
    BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(file.toPath(), BasicFileAttributes.class);
    if (dateChecker(attr.lastModifiedTime())) {
        filesToArchive.add(file);
    }
}
doZip(filesToArchive, <resultname>.zip);
```

И в этом случае `doZip` преобразуется в вариант наподобии:

```
private static void doZip(List<File> files, String archiveName){
    try {
        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(archiveName));
        out.setLevel(9);

        for (File file : files) {
            out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getName()));
            write(new FileInputStream(dir), out);
        }

        out.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ!